# Are fonts used by an PySide2 application packed with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, fonts, pyinstaller, pyside2

In my PySide2 application, I initialize QFont objects to draw some text using a QPainter. Now my question is, whether or not the fonts (ttf-files or something like that) are automatically packed when running PyInstaller on that project.

I already ran the application on my Windows and MacOS machine, and the Mac used another font than the PC because the font was not available on the Mac. Unfortunately the exe created with PyInstaller is not Cross-Plattform so I can not test whether or not it would work with the exe.

Uses the exe another font when ran on a machine where the font is not available? If so, is there a way to include the font in that exe?

Comment: If you want to use static resources like .ttf then you have 2 options: datas from pyinstaller or qrc from Qt.

Comment: @eyllanesc Is that static resource automatically recognized by the PySide application? I.e. is it possible to use `QFont("Yu Gothic", 14)` without a reference to that resource?

Comment: with datas: `id_ = addApplicationFont(resource_path("your.ttf"))`, .qrc:  `id_ = addApplicationFont(":/your.ttf")`